I want to change the color of a listview entry to show that it is a duplicate of a value already in the sheet
My listview is on a userform.  When I execute my code, it changes the color of all entries in the listview.  I want it to change only the current entry.  E.g.; If the entries are all black (not dupes) and I add an entry that is a dupe and change the forecolor to blue, all preceeding entries become blue as well. Here is my code:
Private Sub addtolv()
    Dim dupe As Boolean
    Dim li As ListItem
    ' note: RecordNumber writecolumn and LASTROW are globals
    dupe = False
    With ListView1
        ' check if already in columnm
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(ThisWorkbook.writecolumn & "2:" & ThisWorkbook.writecolumn & CStr(LASTROW)), Range("B" & RecordNumber)) = 0 
Then
            .ForeColor = vbBlack
        Else
            dupe = True
                .ForeColor = vbBlue
        End If
        Set li = .ListItems.Add(, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & 
RecordNumber), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & RecordNumber), 0)
        li.SubItems(1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & RecordNumber)
        li.SubItems(2) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & RecordNumber)
        li.SubItems(3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & RecordNumber)
        li.SubItems(4) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & RecordNumber)
        li.SubItems(5) = RecordNumber
    End With
End Sub

After setting li, I have tried setting the forecolor using li.ForeColor but that didn't change the colors at all.

Read this question. There is a suggested workaround in the comments. Answer the question yourself if you get it to work.

More suggestions in the answers to this question.

I was using the primary entry as a hidden field (width 0). I can only change the color of the primary entry.  When I readjusted the fields I got the result I desired.  Don't know why all entries were changing.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
